# How to access jsTree node attributes after checkbox was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I would like to know how to access jsTree node attributes after the node's checkbox was clicked.

I use `$("#jstree").bind('check_node.jstree', function(e, data) {` to trigger my code after the checkbox was clicked.

Now I want to access node's attributes. But I don't know how to use `data` object so I can get the attributes. So let's say in my jsfiddle I want to display the value of the attribute along with the text "clicked and checked"

Could you please explain how & why? I am lost how to reference jsTree/jQuery objects.

[jsfiddle working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/T6Hbq/20/)

**==== Update**

In jsTree data definition node attributes could be defined. I want to programatically check the attributes and then fire different code base on the attributes. In my case  **"log"** attribute.

```
data = [
    {
        "data": "Basics",
        "attr":{"log":"shared"},
    },
    {
        "data": "All",
        "attr":{"log":"bdrs"},
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean with node attributes, maybe you can inspect data object with console.log

Comment: @juanpastas: I added an update... So let's say in my jsfiddle I want to display the value of the attribute along with the text "clicked and checked" for the node its checkbox was clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could just do:

```
$("#jstree").bind('check_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
    $("#list").append('<BR>clicked and ' + node_is_check(data));
    var node = data.rslt.obj;
    console.log( node.attr("log") ); //shows bdrs when All is checked
});
```

Updated fiddle: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T6Hbq/22/)

Did you mean something like this

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Could you please explain? What is rstl.obj. Why do I have to use it? When do I use it? Thank you.

Comment: @Radek `data.rslt.obj` is the jquery extended node that was clicked, so you can get the required data using this node, pls read the docs to get more details..

Comment: The only reference in doc I found is "rslt" : /* any data the function passed to the event */,`. Could you tell me why I need to use rstl.obj? not only rstl?

Comment: @Radek as the whole "data.rslt.obj" gives you the node that was clicked/checked (as per the docs) , using it allows you to get the required data associated with it... i hope i'm being clear

Comment: I don't understand why I have to use rslt.obj why not only rslt

Comment: @Radek data.rslt would give you the object(within which actual node that was checked exits) while data.rslt.obj wil give you the actual node object that was checked, so using data.rslt.obj allows to get the required data from the checked node..